# Sort by json element at nested level for jsonb data - postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have below table in postgresql which stored JSON data in jsonb type of column.

```
CREATE TABLE "Trial" (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  data jsonb
);
```

Below is the sample json structure

```
{
"id": "000000007001593061",
"core": {
    "groupCode": "DVL",
    "productType": "ZDPS",
    "productGroup": "005001000"
},
"plants": [
    {
        "core": {
            "mrpGroup": "ZMTS",
            "mrpTypeDesc": "MRP",
            "supLeadTime": 777
        },
        "storageLocation": [
            {
                "core": {
                    "storageLocation": "H050"
                }
            },
            {
                "core": {
                    "storageLocation": "H990"
                }
            },
            {
                "core": {
                    "storageLocation": "HM35"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
],
"discriminator": "Material"
```

}

These are the scripts for insert json data

```sql
INSERT INTO "Trial"(data)
VALUES(CAST('{"id":"000000007001593061","core":{"groupCode":"DVL","productType":"ZDPS","productGroup":"005001000"},"plants":[{"core":{"mrpGroup":"ZMTS","mrpTypeDesc":"MRP","supLeadTime":777},"storageLocation":[{"core":{"storageLocation":"H050"}},{"core":{"storageLocation":"H990"}},{"core":{"storageLocation":"HM35"}}]}],"discriminator":"Material"}' AS JSON))

INSERT INTO "Trial"(data)
VALUES(CAST('{"id":"000000000104107816","core":{"groupCode":"ELC","productType":"ZDPS","productGroup":"005001000"},"plants":[{"core":{"mrpGroup":"ZCOM","mrpTypeDesc":"MRP","supLeadTime":28},"storageLocation":[{"core":{"storageLocation":"H050"}},{"core":{"storageLocation":"H990"}}]}],"discriminator":"Material"}' AS JSON))

INSERT INTO "Trial"(data)
VALUES(CAST('{"id":"000000000104107818","core":{"groupCode":"DVK","productType":"ZDPS","productGroup":"005001000"},"plants":[{"core":{"mrpGroup":"ZMTL","mrpTypeDesc":"MRP","supLeadTime":28},"storageLocation":[{"core":{"storageLocation":"H050"}},{"core":{"storageLocation":"H990"}}]}]}' AS JSON))
```

If try to sort by at first level then it works

```
select id,data->'core'->'groupCode' 
from "Trial" 
order by data->'core'->'groupCode' desc
```

But when I try to sort by at nested level, below is the script then it doesn't work for me, I'm for sure I'm wrong for this script but don't know what is it ?  Need assistant if someone knows how to order by at nested level for JSONB data.

```
select id,data->'plants' 
from sap."Trial" 
order by data->'plants'->'core'->'mrpGroup' desc
```

Need assistance for write a query for order by at nested level for JSONB data.

Comment: `plants` is an array, so it can potentially contain hundreds of elements. Which one of those should be used for sorting?

Answer (score 0):

Below query works for me

`SELECT id, data FROM "Trial" ORDER BY jsonb_path_query_array(data, '$.plants[*].core[*].mrpGroup') desc limit 100`